# Shift functor and the origin of the linear decalage isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, homological-algebra, symmetric-monoidal-categories

Let $(\mathbf{Vec}_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{K}),\otimes,\tau)$ be the symmetric monoidal category of $\mathbb{Z}$-graded $\mathbb{K}$-vector spaces, where $\otimes$ is the tensor product of $\mathbb{Z}$-graded vector spaces and $\tau$ is the Koszul symmetry constrain, defined on components $V,W \in \mathbf{Vec}_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{K})$ and homogeneous  elements $v\otimes w \in V\otimes W$ by

$\tau(v\otimes w)=(-1)^{|v||w|}w\otimes v$.

---

The first part of the question is related to the shifting functor
$(\cdot)[1]:\mathbf{Vec}_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{K})\to \mathbf{Vec}_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{K})$. Not much concrete is given in the literure about it. I know that,
given an object $V\in \mathbf{Vec}_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{K})$ the shifted graded vector space $V[1]$ is given by $(V[1])_k:= V_{k+1}$, but I don't know how it acts on graded linear maps $f:V \to W$. So how exactly works this functor? Moreover is it (somewhat) monoidal or what is its precise relation to the Koszul structure $(\otimes,\tau)$?

---

The second part of the question is related to the 'canonical map' underlying 
the linear decalage ismorphism. This map is given by

$V \otimes \mathbb{K}[1] \to V[1]\;;\; v \otimes 1_{\mathbb{K}[1]}\mapsto 
(-1)^{|v|}v[1]$ $\text{ }\text{ }$[eq.(1)]

and here the question is: 'what is this map'? Is it the component-wise description
of a natural isomorphism from the previous mentioned shift functor $(\cdot)[1]$
to the 'tensoring with $\mathbb{K}[1]$' functor, i.e the functor 
$(\cdot)\otimes\mathbb{K}[1]:\mathbf{Vec}_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{K})\to \mathbf{Vec}_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{K})$?

If yes, then the question arise what properties has $(\cdot)\otimes\mathbb{K}[1]$? Is it symmetric monoidal in some way? Is the 'canonical isomorphism'
[eq.(1)] a natural isomorphism of symm. mon. functors?

If not, what else is the precise meaning of eq.(1)?

---

In homological algebra the various decalage isomorpisms arising from these transformations are of great importance, mastering complicated computational details and I'm surprised that the above problems were not handled clearly in any reference book I read.

---

Answering only parts of this bunch of questions, is of course welcome.

Comment: $(f[1])_k=f_{k+1}$ The shift functor is not monoidal since $k[1]\otimes k[1]=k[2]\neq k[1]=(k\otimes k)[1]$. Here $k$ is the field concentrated in degree $0$. As for the second question, rather than giving an answer (which would be biased by my own convenitions) I'd suggest that you declare all these functors and (natural) transformations to satisfy the properties you wish and then check whether they are compatible. This is what people usually do, and there are different ways of choosing signs, etc. It's just conventions.

Comment: Thanks for the comment to the first question. However I don't understand your comment to the second one. What conventions are subjective here? I have declared all functors above, didn't I?

Comment: Since the shift functor is not monoidal, I wonder about the origin of the sign in eq.(1). It must somehow interact with the Koszul constrain.

Comment: Sign conventions can be modified, e.g. the sign in eq.(1).

Comment: So can you tell a little more? How and why can it be modified? Since THAT is precisely the question? I don't know how the sign factor in eq.(1) arises from higher priciples, therefore I although don't know how it can be modified. It must be related to $\tau$ somehow (otherwise it wouldn't be natural), but I don't see it.

Comment: Eventually I should add, that I think that $v\otimes 1_{\mathbb{K}[1]}\mapsto (-1)^{|v[1]|}v[1]$ is the correct canonical map, but the map above appears, too. Therefore a judge from a higher perspective should be made, since I think the sign is **not** a convention and only one 'canonical isom.' is correct. (The one in this comment)

Comment: I guess the correct version of eq 1 should be $\mathbb{K}[1]\otimes V \to V[1]$, with a hidden $\tau$. That is, one should have a "no sign" canonical isomorphism $V\otimes \mathbb{K}[1] \to V[1]$ and what one is doing is composing it with the isomorphism $\tau$. This makes the $(-1)^{|v|}$ sign appear. By the way, checking this in a paper of mine (L_oo structures on mapping cones) I just saw that with Marco Manetti we are correctly writing $\mathbb{K}[1]\otimes V$ in the text but immeditely after that we have the incorrect and misleading $V\otimes \mathbb{K}[1]$ in the displayed equation :(

Comment: On second thougth, the displayed equation I have in "L_oo structures..." is correct: what it was meant there is that the no sign isomorphism is $\mathbb{K}[1]\otimes V\to V[1]$, given by $1_{[1]}\otimes v\mapsto v_{[1]}$ and as a consequence of this, the isomorphism $V\otimes \mathbb{K}[1]\to V[1]$ gets a $(-1)^{|v|}$ sign. Actually, writing $v_{[1]}$ with the subscript on the right is very confusing: a much better notation is $sv$, so that the suspesion isomorphism is s\otimes v\mapsto sv$, as in Loday-Vallette book. Sorry for having been confusing in the first answer.